# ffmpeg c#asp video conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg

> I am trying to convert one flv video to mp4 video. Why this
>   following code results error? it gives exception as "No process is
>   associated with this object." The parameters

`"Path_FFMPEG"="E:\\Arun Kumar\\Main Project\\Advertisement Demo\\Advertisementdemo\\Advertisementdemo\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"    and "strParam"="-i E:\\Arun Kumar\\Main Project\\Advertisement Demo\\Advertisementdemo\\Advertisementdemo\\Videos\\cars1.flv -same_quant E:\\Arun Kumar\\Main Project\\Advertisement Demo\\Advertisementdemo\\Advertisementdemo\\Videos\\ConvertedFiles\\cars1.mp4"`

```
Process ffmpeg = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path_FFMPEG, strParam);
ffmpeg_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
ffmpeg_StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ffmpeg.StartInfo = ffmpeg_StartInfo;
ffmpeg_StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
ffmpeg.Start();
ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
ffmpeg.Close();
ffmpeg.Dispose();
ffmpeg = null;
```

Comment: on which line is this error occurs

Answer (score 0):

try this code (assuming your mp4 is named video):

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = //PHYSICAL path to ffmpeg (use \\ instead of \);
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i video.flv video.mp4
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```